# Finding Phantom Exponential value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find an exponential value in an expression. Which is quite straight forward but for some, the result does not show the exponential value on screen but it evaluate as a scientific number.

Here is the code I am using

```
   declare @i as float
   declare @j as float
   set @i = 100
   set @j = 3700000.00

   select
   Cast((Isnull(@i, 0) + Isnull(@j, 0))  AS FLOAT) as 'TheSum',
    CASE 
    WHEN 
    CHARINDEX('E',  Cast((Isnull(@i, 0) + Isnull(@j, 0))  AS FLOAT)) > 0
     THEN '0' -- The expression have an exponential value
    ELSE  Cast((Isnull(@i, 0) + Isnull(@j, 0))  AS FLOAT)
    END AS 'Value'
```

the for the above query is

[image: Rsult]

Even though the sum of the two variables shows no exponential value but the query above says that it contains an exponential value.

[Here is the link for the code](http://rextester.com/TUR70698)

Could anyone please explain this phenomenon.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think an "exponential value" is and what is this code supposed to be good for? Scientific notation is way of formatting a number, it has nothing to do with its value (directly). Checking a string for `E` is just... bad. Or at the very least pointless. If this is just an academic question, that's fine, but if this code is supposed to do something in production, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is quite apparent if you try to run the following query

```
   select CAST( Cast((Isnull(@i, 0) + Isnull(@j, 0))  AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(100))
```

output from this query is

```
3.7001e+006
```

This happens because `CHARINDEX` function expects a character input to second parameter and implicitly casts `Cast((Isnull(@i, 0) + Isnull(@j, 0))  AS FLOAT)` as character expression(`3.7001e+006`), which does contain character `e` at 7 poistion

See [MSDN documentation for CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) function which states this

> -- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse
>
> CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ]
> )
>
> *expressionToFind*
> Is a character expression that contains the sequence
> to be found. expressionToFind is limited to 8000 characters.
>
> *expressionToSearch* Is a **character** expression to be searched.
>
> *start_location* Is an integer or bigint expression at which the search
> starts. If start_location is not specified, is a negative number, or
> is 0, the search starts at the beginning of expressionToSearch.